# Xpages links in mobile not working

Tags: android, mobile, xpages

A very simple xpage with mobile controls on android version 5 and links do not work.  I have to be missing something simple.  Server version 9.0.1 fp7.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"

>
<xe:singlePageApp
        id="singlePageApp1"
        selectedPageName="PastDue">

        <xe:appPage
            id="appPage4"
            pageName="PastDue"
            resetContent="true">
    <xp:link
        escape="true"
        text="Google"
        id="link1" value="https://www.google.com">
    </xp:link>
    </xe:appPage>
    </xe:singlePageApp>

</xp:view>
```

Additional comments:

Sorry to clarify links are there, but you click them on the android devices and nothing happens, i.e. you don't go to google in the example above.  I don't see any error messages in the console on chrome debugger, I don't see any message in the domino console.  I happen to be using FP 9 for designer.  If I remove the coreex and just have the link control everything works fine in the android device just like everywhere else.  I have searched for answers on this and haven't found it posted elsewhere.

Comment: What do you mean links don't work? Can you click them, or do they just show text and are not clickable? If you can click them, does it just not respond or does it do something weird? Some more info would be helpful....

Comment: Added comments for clarity above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the onclick event on the link

```
<xe:singlePageApp
        id="singlePageApp1"
        selectedPageName="PastDue">
        <xe:appPage id="appPage1" pageName="PastDue">
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Google" id="link1">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[location.href="http://www.google.com";]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:link>
        </xe:appPage>

    </xe:singlePageApp>
```

Comment: Perfect this works on everything I have tested, firefox, edge, chrome, safari for pc, iphone, and android devices, even using the mobile theme.  Thank you very much!  The onclick instead of the default value setting was the key with the mobile app in androids.